# Where to place sort()

Tags: python

I'm currently working on this code. I need to extract the min and max value in the list, but for some reason they are extracting the first inputted value and the last inputted value as the max. I want to add the sort() function to sort the values in the list from lower to higher, but I don't really know where to put it. Code's below. The list is called ages.

```
def getAges():
    agesAmount= int(input("How many ages do you want to evaluate: "))
    while agesAmount!= 0:
        ages= []
        numAge= 1
        for i in range(agesAmount):
            ages.append(input("Enter age "+str(numAge)+": "))
            numAge+= 1
        agesAmount //= 10
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you define `edades`? In order to make your question clear for people who want to help you with that, you need to provide any variable you have mentioned in your question properly.

Comment: Sorry, I had to translate becasue it is originally in spanish. I just changed it.

Comment: No worries. Just note that `cantidadE` is still missing:(.

Comment: Is `ages` a list of integers or a list of strings?

Comment: I believe is a list of strings

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani just changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your ages to integer

```
ages.append(int(input("Enter age "+str(numAge)+": ")))
```

moreover you don't need numAge

```
while agesAmount!= 0:
    ages= []
    for i in range(agesAmount):
        ages.append(int(input("Enter age "+str(i)+": ")))
    ages.sort()
    print(ages)
```

Comment: I did this and it is sorting them well now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Suggestion: `ages.append(int(input(f"Enter age {numAge}: ")))`

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest to you is what follows:

```py
def getAges():
    agesAmount= int(input("How many ages do you want to evaluate: "))
    while agesAmount!= 0:
        ages= []
        numAge= 1
        for i in range(agesAmount):
            ages.append(input("Enter age "+str(numAge)+": "))
            numAge+= 1
        agesAmount //= 10
    return(sorted(ages, key=lambda x: int(x)))
```

##### Example output

```
How many ages do you want to evaluate: 5
Enter age 1: 5
Enter age 2: 4
Enter age 3: 3
Enter age 4: 1
Enter age 5: 2
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

`sorted` takes two arguments (mostly just one, but you can always consider adding a `key` argument to make a pattern for sorting). The former is an iterable object and the latter, as said before, is a pattern for sorting. If you are explicitly interested in just using `sort` function, follow the next snippet:

```py
def getAges():
    agesAmount= int(input("How many ages do you want to evaluate: "))
    while agesAmount!= 0:
        ages= []
        numAge= 1
        for i in range(agesAmount):
            ages.append(input("Enter age "+str(numAge)+": "))
            numAge+= 1
        agesAmount //= 10
    ages.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
    return(ages)
```

Note that, `sort` function in List objects use variable by reference, so you will just need to call it on the variable without assigning its output to any other variable. It will do the job for you. The output of the code above would be the same as the first code snippet.